# responsive design for website not scrolling in Mobile phones

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am designing a responsive website. It works fine in desktop but when i test in Mobile phones ,I am not able to scroll the page. So i can see only content which fit in the device height.
Note: I have even included  meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width",initial-scale-1.0"
Please Help me :-)

Comment: We can't help you unless you post some code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You are not using fixed/absolute values for the body (or content), are you?

Comment: @thordarson :Sorry for the delay.                                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
      <link href="assets/css/bb.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/bbresponsive.css" rel="stylesheet"> <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script> did i miss something specific to mobiles?

Comment: @inhan: No as far as height is considered i am not using any fixed vales. I use it only in width

Comment: Fixed!! I included iscroll for a dialog box. Removed iscroll for time being. Now its working.

Answer (score 3):

Its been a year since you asked this question, but my answer might help someone.

Make sure you haven't use **`body{ overflow: hidden}`**, because that will hide content which is not visible in initial screen.

EDIT: If you want to hide horizontal scroll which is coming because of unknown reason, use `body{overflow-x: hidden}`. However, I recommend you to find reason behind horizontal scroll.