# Properly highlight active section in navigation bar on different devices

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, navbar

I used `window.pageYOffset` and `window.onscroll` function in JavaScript to add "active" class to the navbar link of a section that I'm currently on.
The problem is that the scroll Y (from the top) value is different on different devices because of screen size I suppose.

What would be the best way to make this feature work properly on all devices?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [responsive design for website not scrolling in Mobile phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775101/responsive-design-for-website-not-scrolling-in-mobile-phones)

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic No everything scrolls fine. The problem is that I want to get current position on the page and use it to change elements but since I use scroll values for it, I get different ones on every devices because of their different sizes

Comment: That's why you need to make it "responsive". Read more about that online.